# PHP file containing base64_decode shows up on server

Tags: php, joomla, base64

My server has a hole somewhere, and I need some help to plug it. A PHP file containing **base64** encoded code keeps showing up in my Joomla website.

I was  blacklisted at first ([kelihos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelihos_botnet) was listed as a reason) and discovered that I have a number of PHP files with random, but human friendly (login.php, file.php, alias75.php ... ), names in the Joomla directory. All files had main portion of the script after base64_decode function. Here is an example of the listing of such file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 155232 Dec 24 18:51 file.php
```

Note the date & time. Night before christmass. This is always the same - the file shows up this mornig at 6 am with a date from 24th Dec. Can this be a clue maybe? Here is the snippet of the actual code:

```
<?php
function jqgwuawwjs($rlkr, $fikixpq){$wynuczq = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($rlkr); $i++){$wynuczq .= isset($fikixpq[$rlkr[$i]]) ? $fikixpq[$rlkr[$i]] : $rlkr[$i];}
$jeb="base64_decode";return $jeb($wynuczq);}
$ldo = 'dGCoZSRV5id3buS9XQR9iuMT59Xg1zcSKz0Ok0OUZYcOipECsx'.
'aDIGRDiuS9XQR9X9Xg1PUOk0OUZYcOipECsxaDIYFHiuSH5YE2sGCTICR6ZY2Cb90ayxqmxq7V5iWv'.
```

this continues for the next 1900 lines & ending with:

```
;
$zmdjyoxo = Array('1'=>'I', '0'=>'w', '3'=>'o', '2'=>'1', '5'=>'Z', '4'=>'q', '7'=>'B', '6'=>'0', '9'=>'y', '8'=>'6', 'A'=>'K', 'C'=>'l', 'B'=>'i', 'E'=>'N', 'D'=>'n', 'G'=>'G', 'F'=>'F', 'I'=>'b', 'H'=>'4', 'K'=>'T', 'J'=>'8', 'M'=>'x', 'L'=>'L', 'O'=>'p', 'N'=>'P', 'Q'=>'m', 'P'=>'D', 'S'=>'V', 'R'=>'9', 'U'=>'A', 'T'=>'v', 'W'=>'R', 'V'=>'z', 'Y'=>'W', 'X'=>'c', 'Z'=>'a', 'a'=>'g', 'c'=>'5', 'b'=>'J', 'e'=>'t', 'd'=>'Q', 'g'=>'s', 'f'=>'j', 'i'=>'X', 'h'=>'U', 'k'=>'O', 'j'=>'r', 'm'=>'7', 'l'=>'e', 'o'=>'u', 'n'=>'h', 'q'=>'k', 'p'=>'3', 's'=>'d', 'r'=>'Y', 'u'=>'2', 't'=>'S', 'w'=>'H', 'v'=>'f', 'y'=>'M', 'x'=>'C', 'z'=>'E');
eval(jqgwuawwjs($ldo, $zmdjyoxo));?>
```

When you change eval to print this is what comes out (code is to big for body of message - here is the link to pastebin):

http://pastebin.com/xcY3wQs6

I deleted all these files from the server, changed root password, mysql password, joomla password & activated two-factor authentication for joomla administrator.

I noticed strange behavior a month ago, but before investigating the problem (maybe related to this) my provider - **Host9** had a catastrophic failure. This left me without website & mail server from 24. Dec 15 - 12. Jan 16 (!).
From then, I have a cron job that looks for these php files. Of course, deleting them is resolving only half the problem. The question is how is it that these files keep popping up?

I have a VPS with:

Ubuntu Server Linux 3.13.0-63-generic on x86_64

Apache/2.4.7

PHP 5.5.9

Joomla 3.4.8

The file showd up after 6:00 am, so I include apache2 access.log at about that time:

```
61.135.190.71 - - [27/Jan/2016:22:56:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 430 "http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=www" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
208.52.154.243 - - [28/Jan/2016:01:23:44 +0000] "GET /dbadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.0" 404 458 "-" "-"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:02:56:54 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:02:56:55 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:02:56:56 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:06:43:36 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:06:56:03 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:11:58 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:12:20 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:12:21 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:12:30 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:12:34 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:13:23 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:13:24 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:13:26 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:26:30 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:26:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:26:32 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:29:28 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
78.155.39.214 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:47:02 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
78.155.39.214 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:47:03 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/messages.php?lang=en&amp;db=&amp;token=79eab716479466d5c44116323db94bb0 HTTP/1.1" 200 17157 "http://207.210.201.88/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
78.155.39.214 - - [28/Jan/2016:07:47:03 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&amp;token=79eab716479466d5c44116323db94bb0&amp;nocache=4147360344ltr HTTP/1.1" 200 17556 "http://my.ip.add.ress/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:08:03:53 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:08:03:55 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:08:03:57 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:08:04:01 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:08:04:17 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jan/2016:08:04:18 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

Apache2 error.log

```
[Mon Jan 25 03:30:13.688765 2016] [:error] [pid 25830] [client 95.213.177.123:41264] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Jan 25 03:49:23.091859 2016] [:error] [pid 4517] [client 208.52.154.243:37227] script '/var/www/moadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 25 07:40:45.016456 2016] [:error] [pid 19847] [client 95.213.177.124:38892] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Mon Jan 25 23:50:34.056409 2016] [:error] [pid 2434] [client 185.25.151.159:34885] script '/var/www/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Jan 26 06:47:48.641496 2016] [:error] [pid 6043] [client 95.213.177.122:42690] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Jan 26 10:58:48.569545 2016] [:error] [pid 14076] [client 95.213.177.123:32251] script '/var/www/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Tue Jan 26 15:06:42.084295 2016] [core:error] [pid 25454] [client 169.229.3.91:42376] AH00135: Invalid method in request c'\xfdF\x9c\xd8\x02\xb9N\xfa\x8d\xc6J(\x9c\xb0\x04\xa3%
[Thu Jan 28 08:01:43.830310 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3932] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jan 28 08:01:44.884060 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26468] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 28 08:01:44.884678 2016] [core:notice] [pid 26468] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jan 28 08:21:31.499215 2016] [:error] [pid 26475] [client 78.155.39.214:50308] script '/var/www/phpmyadmin.css.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: do you have access to the apache logs?

Comment: if the files keep reappearing something on the server is compromised which allows them to still access to it. sadly often the easiest thing to get rid of this is doing a clean install with completely different passwords and clean sources. check everything you copy over twice

Comment: I just added the relevant parts of apache2 log files

Comment: Yup, you've been hacked, are still being hacked, probably will continue to be hacked in future. Clean install, update everything, don't give the web server ownership or write permissions in your joomla folder, use an intrusion detection system to spot unexpectedly modified files (there are probably joomla plugins for that).

Comment: @Synchro - what are you seeing in the log files? If I reinstall, how do I know this is solving the problem? The machine I am running is stable ubuntu server with things incrementally added. It would take me a month to get it back to its original state - and then I would not be sure that I did what it takes.

Comment: Sure, you're running a stable server *that allows unknown third parties to write random junk into the system*, compromising everything you have. If you make it impossible for them to do that on a new deployment, you will have solved that particular problem, and a new install guarantees that you are free of infection - trying to find everything they might have touched is a losing battle - you only have to miss one thig for it to be wide open to continued and repeated abuse. It's not just your server that's at risk, it's everyone who visits it, since these things usually inject XSS attacks.

Comment: @Synchro - I think we have a misunderstanding: I said _stable ubuntu server_ but I should have said LTS Ubuntu Server. I don't consider it stable in the sense of _impenetrable_, just a version that is been around for long. It has known problems that can be fixed. If I do what you suggest, and reinstall everything, the attacks continue, what would be the next step?

Comment: It's not an ubuntu problem, it's a config and joomla problem. Somewhere you have an unpatched joomla vulnerability that allows an external party to write content into executable PHP files. At the same time your web server config allows such writes to occur. Fix either one and you have closed the hole - the latter is easier, just `chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/www/mysite` and joomla will not be able to write anywhere. That may block functionality such as user image uploads or joomla automated updates, but that's a better problem to have.

Comment: @Synchro - You are right, forbidding joomla to write files will be annoying, but it would help stop the abuse. Can I then "catch" the script that tries to write the new file - is that what tripwire is for?

Comment: Yes - tripwire, bro, [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) and many other tools will do this. It may be useful to simply use a git repo for your web root as then you can see exactly what has changed and easily undo things that should not have happened. Bear in mind that systems like that only show you that someone succeeded in breaking in, doesn't do anything to prevent it happening.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems like a malware script and is encoded to protect. I would suggest you to delete it using a program.

Try narnia gurdian , http://github.com/Pilskalns/Narnia-Guardian

try the above resource to remove those encoded snippet from all your files. That is easy to setup and easy to use also. All you just need to keep patients.

Comment: I have to agree. I have a cron job that does that, but that is like having a pump on a leaking ship, good enough until you get to the harbor.